# Why the evaluation of this Gaussian integral takes so much time?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I want the following Gaussian function integrated for both `x` and `y` however it is not evaluated by Mathematica.

```
  func=(E^(-λ^2 (-l1 x Cos[t1]^2 + (l1 + l2) y Cos[t1] Sin[t2] + 
 l2 x Sin[t2]^2)^2 - (l2 y Cos[t1]^2 + (l1 + l2) x Cos[t1] Sin[
  t2] - l1 y Sin[t2]^2)^2) l1 l2 y^4 λ)/π

Integrate[func, {x, -∞, ∞}, {y, -∞, \
∞}]
```

It looks complicated however it is not. It is Gaussian for `x` and `y` and all the other parameters are set as real using `$Assumptions`.

Comment: Does it actually produce a result? I've evaluated integrals that have taken an hour or two to process, have you tried `NIntegrate[...]` and defined a step size?

Comment: Thx for the suggestions. It doesn't produce anything. I should do it analytically. I think I will try another approach to solve my problem circumventing this integral.

Comment: I think another problem is you don't give any values to your constants. Evaluate the integral as a function of those constants so `IntegralResult[l1_,t1,...]=...` and try again. I think there are probably too many parameters here...